# How do you report a user input error without a print statement?

Tags: c++, error-handling

Here is my C++ function. I am supposed to report a user input error if left < 0 || right < 0 || top < 0 || bottom < 0 || height <= 0 || width <= 0 || height > 1200 || width > 1600 || bottom > 1200 || right > 1600. However, I cannot use any print statements. How else could I report a user error?

Note: this code is a function that determines the distance range a person is from a camera using the coordinates of detected faces.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void getDistance(int left, int right, int top, int bottom, bool isCNN, double& minDistance, double& maxDistance)
{

    int height = bottom - top;
    int width = right - left;
    if (left < 0 || right < 0 || top < 0 || bottom < 0 || height <= 0 || width <= 0 || height > 1200 || width > 1600 || bottom > 1200 || right > 1600)
    {

    }
    else if (isCNN)
    {
        if (width >= 215 && height >= 281)
            minDistance = 0, maxDistance = 14;
        else if (width >= 124 && height >= 167)
            minDistance = 14, maxDistance = 33.75;
        else if (width >= 76 && height >= 111)
            minDistance = 33.75, maxDistance = 53.5;
        else if (width >= 56 && height >= 94)
            minDistance = 53.5, maxDistance = 73.25;
        else if (width >= 49 && height >= 84)
            minDistance = 73.25, maxDistance = 93;
        else if (width >= 41 && height >= 71)
            minDistance = 93, maxDistance = 112.75;
        else if (width >= 28 && height >= 57)
            minDistance = 112.75, maxDistance = 172;
        else if (width >= 23 && height >= 49)
            minDistance = 172, maxDistance = 270.75;
        else
            minDistance = 270.75, maxDistance = 480;
    }
    else
    {
        if (width >= 330)
            minDistance = 0, maxDistance = 6.375;
        else if (width >= 238)
            minDistance = 6.375, maxDistance = 16.25;
        else if (width >= 168)
            minDistance = 16.25, maxDistance = 26.125;
        else if (width >= 122)
            minDistance = 26.125, maxDistance = 36;
        else if (width >= 108)
            minDistance = 36, maxDistance = 55.75;
        else if (width >= 91)
            minDistance = 55.75, maxDistance = 75.5;
        else
            minDistance = 75.5, maxDistance = 144;
    }
}
int main()
{
    double min = NULL;
    double max= NULL;
    getDistance(-766, 981, 328, 609, false, min, max);
        cout << "Minimum distance is " << min << " inches\n";
        cout << "Maximum distance is " << max << " inches\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _"... I cannot use any print statements..."_ you need to say why so we can suggest alternatives.  No point coming up with ideas/answers only to discover this is an assignment with constraints.

Comment: Hint: This code is crying out for some look-up tables and not this mess of confusing comparisons and assignments.

Comment: Given how many branches you've got here, testing this code is going to be a total nightmare. I hope for your sake you're using a unit test suite of some kind so you can validate that all of these numbers are accurate. It's pretty easy to acdidentally delete a character, not notice, save, compile, deploy, and then later get a report that under some narrow cicumstnace everything goes screwy.

Comment: What do you mean by you can't use a print statement?

Comment: In C++ code like this would `throw` an exception and some other part of the code would be responsible for the `catch` and error presentation.

Comment: Any way you can change the type of `left`, `right` , etc to an unsigned type so you can ditch all the less than zero tests by killing the error at the source?

Comment: Well, I suppose you could design a device with wires to electrocute the user, a device driver that defines an interface for programs to interact with that device,  and write your code so it triggers that device.    Such a program (and device) would have a severe problem of user-acceptance though.   Seriously, though, if you have a requirement to "not use a print statement to report an error" you need to specify a requirement for how errors might be reported.   As such - voting to close , since your question is unclear, and assuming things are possible that are not.

Answer (score 1):

The following approaches have all been used in the real world.

1. Change the return type to bool or int, and return a value representing the error.
2. Throw an exception.
3. Quietly return without breaking anything, but without doing anything either.
4. Make an irritating beep but otherwise give no clue what is wrong.
5. Attempt to do the best thing -- by using a safe default, or clamping the offending value into the desired range.
6. Log the error to a file.

You can probably select a similar approach depending on your exact situation. When deciding how to handle errors, you also need to carefully consider whether they are actually user errors, logic errors, or system errors.

Comment: after c++17, std::optional is another option

Answer (score 0):

You state that you want to "report an error without using a print statement", but if that just means you don't want to use `cout`, you could use `cerr` instead. `cerr` is intended for error output.

```
cerr << "Error message";
```

Alternatively, you could write an error message to a file:

```
ofstream file;
file.open("error_log.txt");
file << "Error message\n";
file.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have marked this post as C++.

> I am supposed to report a user input error if "left < 0 || ... || right > 1600". 
>   However, I cannot use any print statements. How else could I report a user error?

A minor part of the Linux philosophy is the idea that success causes no 'noise'.

Without using print, printf, nor cout, we *can* still cause the *"noise of failure"*.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>  // max and min double
#include <cassert>

class T651_t
{
public:

   T651_t() = default;
   ~T651_t() = default;

   int operator()() { return exec();  }

private: // methods

   int exec()
      {
       //double min = std::numeric_limits<double>::min();        // 2.22507e-308 units - lowest  pos value
         double min = std::numeric_limits<double>::max() * -1.0; // 1.79769e+308 units - lowest  neg value
         double max = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();        // 1.79769e+308 units - highest pos value

         std::cout << "\n  Min (lowest   neg) double is " << min << " units";
         std::cout << "\n  Max (hightest pos) double is  " << max << " units";

         getDistance(-766, 981, 328, 609, false, min, max);

         std::cout << "\n  Minimum distance is " << min << " units";
         std::cout << "\n  Maximum distance is  " << max << " units"; 
         std::cout << std::endl;

         return 0;
      }

   void getDistance(int left, int right, int top, int bottom, bool isCNN,
                    double& minDistance, double& maxDistance)
      {
         int height = bottom - top;
         int width  = right  - left;

         if(false) // diagnostic ONLY
           std::cout << "\n  >>>" << left
                     << "  "   << right
                     << "  "   << top
                     << "  "   << bottom
                     << "  "   << minDistance
                     << "  "   << maxDistance
                     << "  "   << isCNN
                     << "  "   << height
                     << "  "   << width
                     << "<<<" << std::endl;
         {
            // how to display "invalid input error" with no print nor cout
            // assert is a failure noise, the line number
            //         reported identifies which failure
            assert ( !(left < 0) );      
            assert ( !(right < 0) );
            assert ( !(top < 0) );
            assert ( !(bottom < 0) );
            assert ( !(height <= 0) );
            assert ( !(width <= 0) );
            assert ( !(height > 1200) );
            assert ( !(width > 1600) );
            assert ( !(bottom > 1200) );
            assert ( !(right > 1600) );
         }
         if (isCNN)
         {
           // ...
         }
         else  // !isCNN
         {
            // ...
         }
      } // void getDistance(...)

}; // class T651_t


int main(int, char* *) { return T651_t()(); }
```

Output:

```
R6xx: dumy651.cc
rm -f dumy651
g++ -m64  -O3 -ggdb -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Wnon-virtual-dtor -pedantic -Werror=vla -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wconversion -Wpointer-arith -Wunused -Wold-style-cast -Woverloaded-virtual   -O0   dumy651.cc  -o dumy651  -L../../bag -lbag_i686 -lposix_i686 -lrt -pthread

real    0m1.149s
user    0m0.996s
sys 0m0.123s

  Min (lowest   neg) double is -1.79769e+308 units
  Max (hightest pos) double is  1.79769e+308 units
dumy651: dumy651.cc:63: void T651_t::getDistance(int, int, int, int, bool, double&, double&): Assertion `!(left < 0)' failed.
/bin/bash: line 1:  5151 Aborted                 (core dumped) ./dumy651
```

Line 63 is the    "assert ( !(left < 0) );"

Note:  class T651_t is a functor.